# Hardening wordpress: blocking /includes with htaccess

Tags: htaccess, include, customization

This page

https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/

says this should be included in the .htaccess file to block requests for files inside the includes dir.

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
...
```

How does that work ? As far as I can read it, it only specifies *not* to rewrite certain urls (using -), and then fails to actually rewrite all other requests. Is there something missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> How does that work ? As far as I can read it, it only specifies not to
>   rewrite certain urls (using -),

These files are *included* within the WordPress PHP scripts, so there's no need to access them in the browser, **but** notice the rewrite *flags*.

Here's some information on the `F`, `L` and `S` *flags* from the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html):

> Using the [F] flag causes the server to return a 403 Forbidden status
>   code to the client.
>
> When using [F], an [L] is implied - that is, the response is returned
>   immediately, and no further rules are evaluated.
>
> The [S] flag is used to skip rules that you don't want to run. The
>   syntax of the skip flag is [S=N], where N signifies the number of
>   rules to skip (provided the RewriteRule matches). This can be thought
>   of as a goto statement in your rewrite ruleset.

You ask:

> and then fails to actually rewrite all other requests.

**no**, all other HTTP requests, that do not match the security rewrites, go to the `# BEGIN WordPress` part

So let's check out the number of files affected by these security rewrite rules:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/includes/*                 -  62 PHP files
http://example.com/wp-includes/*.php                   - 110 PHP files
http://example.com/wp-includes/theme-compat/*          -   5 PHP files
http://example.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/*.php  -   0 PHP files
```

according to my WordPress 3.9.1 install.

Answer (score 0):

Note for future readers:

The third rewrite rule provided under the **[Securing wp-includes](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#securing-wp-includes)** section of the original wordpress.org [Hardening Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) support article, only blocks access to scripts in the parent `wp-includes` directory.

This leaves scripts in `wp-includes/subdirectories` vulnerable to attack, as seen in the Make WordPress Core Ticket [#49499](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49499).

The below code block however, updates the third rewrite rule to also cover wp-includes subdirectories as well, per **[this blog post](https://www.namehero.com/startup/the-right-way-to-block-php-files-in-wp-includes-in-wordpress/)**.

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes\/.*\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```